# How to make a transparent image a non transparent one?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, transparency

I am a newbie to Photoshop and I have a PSD file that contains a transparent button. Now I want to duplicate that button and move it to somewhere else. When I moved it I realized that the button is transparent, and the place where I move it, has another color, so the effect is that original button changes its color in destination place. Now I want to make it nontransparent. How I can do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Layer → Flatten image.

Comment: When I flatten I lose all the other layers. Why? It becomes only one layer and tells me that it can not do the operation because the layer is locked.

Comment: Oh, I got the problem, my layer was ok, the layer on which I was moving was transparent and in layer list was upper that my dublicated layer. So it was just overlapping. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that flattening an image should be the first course of action, especially when you want to duplicate the layer onto another document. Checking transparency, layer style, and blend mode should be done first. Then trying another alternative, as Horatio suggested, is a better tactic than flattening an image.

Answer (score 6):

I would probably leave the button transparent, but add a layer below it with the desired (or solid black with a blend option of color overlay), place the two layers in a group, and then add a layer mask (the same shape as the button) to the group. This way it is trivial to change the color of the button later by changing the color of the new layer I just created below it.